# Copy file contents to the clipboard in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh

I'm generating an SSH key but I don't know how to copy the key from `id_rsa.pub` to the clipboard. I'm using BackBox Linux.

Answer (score -78, accepted):

You can use:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I hope that help you, if not:

[Set up SSH for Git and Mercurial on Mac OSX/Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20150501142423/https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678)

Comment: this only displays it, not copies to clipboard. if you have a really large text, it's not practical to try to highlight it all

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: missing piece: `manually highlight & copy the output of this command with a mouse on the terminal`

Comment: this is the wrong answer

Comment: @Timo Because the issue with the vi is the scroll to copy the content. So if the user just wanted to do it once, it's ok

Comment: The answer may not be complete, but it helped me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 201):

```
xclip -sel c < input_file
```

will copy the contents of `input_file` to clipboard. `xclip` requires installation. To install

```
sudo apt install xclip
```

---

`-sel` stands for `-selection`. `c` is for `clipboard`. Interchangeable.

Capable of much more, I advise reading its man page.

There is also `xsel`. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211826/122065) on Unix SE gives a very thorough answer to this exact question.

Comment: if someone wants to use `alias` for this you can do this: `alias cpc="xclip -sel c < "` and you can use it like so: `cpc file_name.txt`; cpc stands for copy contents

Comment: This only works when you remain in the linux sphere, if it needs copy to clipboard from a Windows app/tool, you're still confined to cat and then selecting the text on display. Anyone's got a better solution for that?

Comment: Why not just `cat input_file | xclip`?

Comment: @YannickCopin: That would be what people refer to as "useless use of `cat`".

Comment: "Error: Can't open display: (null)"
btw it's a server there is no display

Comment: Is it correct to say that the input redirection is unnecessary? In my observation, and based on the manual, `xclip -sel c input_file` has the same effect with a couple fewer keystrokes.

Answer (score 78):

In macOS (but maybe also in Linux operating systems) you can do the following that will directly copy the content of id_rsa.pub to clipboard:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: thank you for posting this answer despite the fact that others would insist on ONLY "linux". I certainly found this useful when i searched for "how to copy from unix terminal clipboard in mac"

Answer (score 40):

This command copies the content of a file into your clipboard:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -i < file.txt
```

Also, this shorter command copies the content of a file into the mouse middle click:

```
xclip < file.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're copying from terminal (like if you use the cat command already posted), highlight the key details and use Ctrl + Shift + C. This should put it on your clipboard. You can also right click and select 'copy' from terminal.

Comment: If the file is larger than the screen (for instance when using vim) then this doesn't really work. Only copies the part you have selected